# Is spin an observable quantity for fundamental particles?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

How we know that the spin of fundamental particles?
For example spin-0, 1/2, 1,2.. What is the experimental facts about spin?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The link does not mention about spin- 0 and spin 3/2 vb., Here I am asking how we know it is spin 1 or 3/2  or 0?

Comment: Check here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31387/how-do-you-find-spin-of-a-particle-from-experimental-data