# A question about spontaneous symmetry breaking at macroscopic limit

Tags: symmetry-breaking, higgs

The question relates to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23083/why-is-the-higgs-boson-spin-0).

Spontaneous symmetry breaking is somehow a volume effect, that in-principle only happens at infinity large system. Weinberg in the second volume of his QFT used a chair demostrated the lost of rotational symmetry due to large scale of the chair.

p. 163

> We do not have to look far for examples of spontaneous symmetry
>   breaking. Consider a chair. The equations governing the atoms of the
>   chair are rotationally symmetric, but a solution of these equations, the
>   actual chair, has a definite orientation in space. Here we will be concerned
>   not so much with the breaking of symmetries by objects like chairs, but
>   rather with the symmetry breaking in the ground state of any realistic
>   quantum field theory, the vacuum.

p.164-165

> Spontaneous symmetry breaking actually occurs only for idealized systems
>   that are infinitely large. The appearance of broken symmetry for a
>   chair arises because it has a macroscopic moment of inertia $I$, so that
>   its ground state is part of a tower of rotationally excited states whose energies are separated by only tiny amounts, of order $\frac{{\hbar}^2}{I}$. This gives the state vector of the chair an exquisite sensitivity to external perturbations; even very weak external fields will shift the energy by much more
>   than the energy difference of these rotational levels. In consequence, any
>   rotationally asymmetric external field will cause the ground state or any
>   other state of the chair with definite angular momentum numbers rapidly
>   to develop components with other angular momentum quantum numbers.
>   The states of the chair that are relatively stable with respect to small
>   external perturbations are not those with definite angular momentum
>   quantum numbers, but rather those with a definite orientation, in which
>   the rotational symmetry of the underlying theory is broken.
>   For the vacuum also,

To a very good approximation, the chair is described by quantum electrodynamics
$$L= -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + i \bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m) \psi  $$
The rotation of chair corresponds to $SO(3)$ group as a subgroup of the Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$. If vacuum is similar with the chair, the rotational symmetry could also break together with global rigid $O(N)$ symmetry. The standard argument that Higgs boson being a scalar, is to keep Lorentz invariance. If the $SO(3)$ rotational symmetry is lost, then this argument is not necessarily valid. Is there any other rationalization for the Higgs boson being scalar?

If vacuum is *not* similar with the chair, why only global rigid $O(N)$ symmetry is broken but not $SO(3)$? Is that a pure guess then confirmed experimentally?

Comment: Yes, everything in SM is basically a pure (POOR) guess. There is no single fundamental idea like in GR or SR. Well, you can say symmetry is good enough fundamental idea, the problem is -- it was discovered by some woman long ago before SM. SM took everything good from Electrodynamics and Mechanics and abused it by smoking QM.